# MP4 video file does not play audio in Quicktime on macOS 10.14

Tags: macos, audio, video, quicktime, video-codecs

Consider the following MP4 audio file, with the following codec information (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> in VLC):
[image: VLC Media Information]

When I open this file with QuickTime, or QuickLook, this file does not play with audio. However, when I open the file with VLC, the audio plays flawlessly.

When I convert the video file with FFmpeg, to a `.mov` file, by using the following command:

```
ffmeg -i file.mp4 output.mov
```

the `.mov` file has the following codec information
(<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> in VLC):
[image: mov file codec information (image)]

Please note that both the original `.mp4` file and the new `.mov` file both use MPEG AAC Audio. When I open the `.mov` file with QuickTime, the audio now works perfectly.

These files are `.mp4` files that are exported from my dashcam (Garmin Dashcam 55). I guess I could convert every file to a `.mov` file before storing them, but I would just like to be able to use the `.mp4` files.

What is going wrong here? What am I missing? Do I need to install additional codecs on my Mac (macOS 10.14.5, nothing extra installed like Perian or whatever, just QuickTime and Final Cut Pro from the MAS)...? Why are the `.mp4` files not playing with audio in QuickTime, but they *are* playing with audio in VLC (I know VLC has its codecs embedded in the .app itself)? Why is the `.mov` playing with audio in QuickTime even though it uses the same audio codec as the `.mp4` file?

Comment: I had to look up the tx3g codec, I've never encoded with it.  Perhaps QT can't handle it?  Can you use the ffmpeg "copy" stream feature to copy your 1st 2 streams (video and AAC), dropping the subtitle (?) stream?  QT might be able to play that, which will tell you that it's just that 3rd stream.

Comment: Yeah if you could narrow down which audio stream contains the actual data (and, if possible, post the offending file), it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi guys, thank you for the replies.

The videos files are copied straight from my Garmin Dashcam 55's SD card onto my internal drive.

This is an example of such a file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ukbvem4u48brkwe/GRMS0017.mp4?dl=0

The audio in VLC plays perfectly but it does not play in QT.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: if this video was still available I'd take a look!